# CardView Elevation cannot be seen when the app starts

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am making an app where there will be a listview in a cardview. Below is the XML code. I wanted to use the elevation, so I did. But it didn't work. So I looked in here some question's answer. I tried most of them, including the dependency, using compatPadding and hardwareAccelerated = "true". But when I run the app in my Redmi 5 mobile, the listview is perfectly shown but the CardView Elevation or shadow below a card cannot be seen, just a normal line. Is there any mistake I made in the below listView layout XML(Not the main activity XML):

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="16dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivMain"
                android:layout_width="352dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/dhaka" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMain"
                android:layout_width="365dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/audiowide"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
                android:layout_width="342dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvMain"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="183dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

If you need the activity_main.xml file code let me know. Thank you

Comment: Remove ‘cardUseCompatPadding’ and then check.

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1' use this it will work surly

Comment: @umesh shakya It tells me to change compileSdkVersion to 27. If I do so, what else will I need to change?

Comment: Have a look at my **Solution** below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Although your layout worked perfectly in my laptop. (Attached an Image below)

[image]

You can try one of the below solutions:

**Solution1:**

*Make your* `hardwareAccelerated = "false"` *in your* `Manifest.xml` *Although, it is not required in most of the cases. (I did not add it in mine, still works)*

**Solution2:**

*Apply certain margin as:* `android:layout_margin="4dp"` *because sometimes you have elevation but it does not seem to appear as it is hidden behind*

**Solution3:**

*Make sure you have **res-auto** schema* `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` *for cardview's elevation*

**Solution4:**

*If none of the above solutions work for you, lastly try adding both the below dependencies:*

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

I my opinion, One of the given solutions must work.

But, the way I see your program, for you, **Solution3** should work. So,

Replace this:

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

with this:

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

**Or** You can also replace `cardview` with `app` in your `cardview` xml as shown below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="16dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    ........ 

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I hope one of the methods will work for you.

Comment: In the design view i can see the shadow below after updating it with your code. But in the phone while running the apk the problem persists.

Comment: @FatinFaiazIsty Which solution did you use.? can you show a screenshot of your device.

Comment: Umang Burman, Thanks sir! Really Appreciate it. I just used contentPadding and the shadow is there somehow. Don't know how. But your ideas helped really a lot. Thank You. The elevation is working now. The shadow is a bit faded but it's there!

Comment: @FatinFaiazIsty I'm glad I could help in any way possible. :)

Comment: Still not working on my device, since I started running Android Pie

Comment: @HarounHajem Did you try all the mentioned solutions?

Answer (score 0):

remove it `app:cardElevation="@dimen/size_3" and use   app:cardElevation="@dimen/size_3"

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="16dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivMain"
                android:layout_width="352dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/dhaka" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMain"
                android:layout_width="365dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/audiowide"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
                android:layout_width="342dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvMain"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="183dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use 
`android:translationZ="5dp"` to make effects of elevation. :)

Comment: With all due respect sir: This could have been a comment.

Comment: You are right, i'm sorry. Just wanna put my solution like response, let me edit. Thanks